# Firebase Safari Google Auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello Im having and issue with Safari and Firebase's authentication process. The code works in Chrome but leaves a blank popup when using safari and doesn't redirect when using SignInWithRedirect. What am I missing? The console log shows all comments but the "Made it" one

Here's the code

```
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    console.log("FB");
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    console.log("Provider");
    firebase
        .auth()
        .getRedirectResult()
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.credential) {
                console.log("Made it");
                // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                // ...
            }
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log("error code: " + errorCode + "\n" + "Error message:" + errorMessage);
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            // ...
        });
    console.log("done");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. Seems like firebase as an entirety was having issues. I had to clear the cache in the preferences. Kinda silly but I followed the article below. Thanks self

[Safari not updating](https://superuser.com/questions/1452556/safari-not-updating-when-i-serve-my-local-changes-on-firebase/1452560#1452560?s=3364b5d44ac3424d9edfccdf6478390c)